# Classifying a classifier

Tags: artificial-intelligence, machine-learning, classification, cluster-analysis

I've implemented a classifier which

- Each iteration receives a parameter object to classify, some objects share a classifiable "property" like a color name.
- Classification parameters could change, so they are parametrized too
  and passed to this classifier at initialization time.
- The classifier implements the classification logic based in the type
  of possible classifications AND the object to classify.

I am VERY confused about the vocabulary used in some articles: [Linear Classifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_classifier), [Feature Values and Vectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Features_%28pattern_recognition%29).

Is this a common form of classifier?
In my approach I see no vectors, no statistical classifications, no hierarchical classificatoin, no machine learning, etc.

Which kind of classifier would be for the computer science literature?

Comment: Would this be more appropriate on Stats.SE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "parameter object" is a feature vector. Your classifier apparently does not involve training so I'd say it's an ad hoc rule-based classifier.

Comment: Thanks, it would be cool if you can provide a link to documentation about simple rule-based classifiers :)